# Freezing mobs dosen't work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I was wondering if there is a problem with NoAI?
Becuase if im correct then this command should spawn a horse that you can can't se and he can't move right? But when i summon it in my minecraft world it dosen't freeze the horse. The horse still moves!

```
/summon Horse ~ ~-2.4 ~ {CustomName:"CHAIR",Type:0,Variant:7,Attributes:[{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:1}],Invulnerable:1,Rotation:[180f,0f],NoAI:1,Silent:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:1,Duration:199999980,ShowParticles:0b}]}
```

No but if you sit on him then he moves

Comment: The command works fine for me. If you mean the animations of the horse, you can't disable those.

Comment: Try a part of the command first to narrow down the cause.

Answer (score 0):

That command is outdated.
Plus, you made the breed "Invisible". Try this command:

> /summon horse ~ ~-2.4 ~ {Silent:1b,Invulnerable:1b,CustomName:"CHAIR",NoAI:1b,Variant:256,Rotation:[180F,0F],ActiveEffects:[{Id:14b,Amplifier:1b,Duration:631138520,ShowParticles:0b}],Attributes:[{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:1}]}

Slap that in a command block!